# Help with rendering a google sketchup file, on blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have inserted a google sketchup file, when i clicked render this happened. It is not rendering, and is turning up pixelated like this, and unclear.[image]

blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Share the "proper" texture.

Comment: Please share the file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and put the link in your question by editing it